# Find the version of a motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, vehicle-identification

I need to know the exact version of my motorcycle, I can't find this information on the frame nor the user manual.
It's a Kawasaki ER-5 sold in October 2005 in France.

I want to replace the fork oil and the service manual states different level regarding the version of the motorcycle.

> Front Fork Oil Level:
>   ER500-**C1 ∼ C3** 127 ±2 mm (5.00 ±0.08 in.)
>   ER500-**C4 ∼** 120 ±2 mm (4.72 ±0.08 in.)

I don't know if I have the C1, C2, C3, C4 or another version.

I noticed the pink slip indicates "ER500A**C2**A" as the type of vehicle but the international identification code is "JKAER500ACA085783"; no "C2" here ...
(Those codes are D.2 and D.2.1 if you are familiar with the french certificates of title.)

Is there a way to know for sure which one I have ?

Comment: @DucatiKiller may know the answer to this.

Comment: I personally cannot identify it *positively*, but would think yours is a "C2" from what you've presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking it up by the VIN. It should be on your frame somewhere. You can look it up at http://www.carfax.com/vin

Also, if it's your motorcycle, you could just split the difference on the fork oil height. The two specs are 7mm apart, so you'd be off by at most 3.5mm.

You could also call your local Kawasaki dealer with the VIN.

Comment: Carfax is great service, but it's not available in Europe (our "VIN" is different, has letter on it...)
I called my Kawasaki dealer and he told me from the identification number that's it's a ER500-C5.
It seems to be correlated with the year of production like so :
2001 Kawasaki ER500-C1 and ER500-D1;
2002 Kawasaki ER500-C2; 
2003 Kawasaki ER500-C3;  
2004 Kawasaki ER500-C4; 
2005 Kawasaki ER500-C5 and ER500-C5P.

Answer (score 2):

I found it, on the last page of the Service Manual there is the correlation between the frame number and the version :
[image: Kawasaki ER5 Service Manual model application]

So mine is a C5, not a C2 as I thought.
And as [zglennie](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/17909/10954) said, you can make a call to your dealer too.